# Python library for "Top-Posting" EML file

Tags: library, python, email

I have an `eml` file that contains a conversation history.
Nearly all email providers automatically concat the conversation history

[image]

For example here `gmail` automatically concats the conversion history (comments #1 - #3)
I have an `eml` of this entire conversion history and I'm trying to reply to the message (which essentially should concat the entire history plus the new textual content afterwards). I wish to reply using `top-posting` strategy and I am seeking a Python library that does that out of the box.

Comment: "history plus the new textual content afterwards": Don't you mean new text before the history?

Comment: Should the Python library actually send the email? Or just generate another .eml file?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul either way is fine. I am sending the message with Amazon ses